# Weird error 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: message is not defined'

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot and it works fine but there's one thing that doesn't work. For some reason, it gives me this error when I try to do something with the bot. `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: message is not defined` I have no idea why. Heres the code that has the error: `const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) =>  message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id).hasPermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES"), { dispose: true }`

Heres's some context of what the bot is if that helps: It's a ticket bot, where members can report problems to mods in a private channel. It creates a channel, and sends a message saying "staff will be with you shortly" and puts reactions so that you can close the ticket. When I try to close the ticket, it gives the error. The error happens around `user.id).haspermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES")` That code is supposed to make people without the MANAGE_NICKNAMES permission unable to use the reactions, and theres no place in the code that i'm supposed to put 'message' so why is this happening?

Comment: did you define message? also it is used "message.guild.[...]"

Comment: i dont know how to define the message, i cant find where to put message

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing places `message` to `reaction.message` and if it doesn't work try using partials